# html fixed nav bar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I tried to make my nav bar fixed. It works, some content flow under it well. But for some reason, a section instead flows over and covers it. Please how can I fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for this. Found the answer. I had to set z-index of the fixed nav bar. Found the answer here - [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp)